# Is this possible to get categories having more than one parent id in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets suppose , i am using this

```
$categories1=get_categories('orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&parent=4');
```

in this line it will return me a list of categories belong to parent=4 category.
I want the list from two parent category, i tried by using comma like

```
$categories1=get_categories('orderby=name&order=ASC&hide_empty=0&parent=4,8');
```

but its returning null array. 
So can it be possible to get categories list from two parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that it only takes an integer not a string, like exclude or include where you can list ids.  You will probably have to make 2 queries and merge the arrays.